# How to use one sidebar to resize two windows/tab at same time

Tags: windows-7

Idk if it's called sidebar or not. But I want to know that how place two windows side by side and then use one side bar to change the size of both windows.

When we place two windows side by side then want one of them to be big and other to be small, we need to make short the size of second windows first and then large the first windows.

In MacOS, the sidebars collapse and we can the size of both windows by moving only one sidebar. But I don't know how to do it in windows 7. So can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try holding windows key then press left/right arrow key. Or drag apps on the left/right most end of the screen and leave it.
This works in Windows 10 but not sure about windows 7.

Comment: It just make two windows half of the screen. But it doesn't allow to make one program short and other large. We need to make one program short first, then make one program large.

Answer (score 0):

[AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) might save you a little bit of time, but it doesn't provide exactly what you want.

AltDrag is a program that lets you move and resize a window with `Alt` + `Left mouse button` and `Alt` + `Right mouse button` respectively. From the website:

> - Use the right mouse button to resize windows. It will resize from the corner or edge you grab closest to.
> - Hold down the Shift key to snap to other windows. You can enable automatic snapping in the options.

So if you hold `Alt` and `Shift`, you can use snap the edge of one window to another with `Right mouse button` instead of manually moving the edge to the desired position.